# ES6 Computed Property in Destructure - Destructure Whole Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this variable:

```
var a = {b:1, c:2, d:'rawr', rawr:10};
```

I want to destructure these into the local scope so I do:

```
var {b, c, d} = a;
```

This works fine but I need to get `rawr` out. I tried this:

```
var {b, c, d, [a.d]} = a;
```

But this gives me `missing : after property id` so I tried:

So I then though to do a two step:

```
var {b, c, d} = a;
var {[d]} = a;
```

However this gives me `SyntaxError: missing : after property id`. Is there anyway to do this in ES6?

Expected result is that:

```
var b = 1;
var c = 2;
var d = 'rawr';
var rawr = 10;
```

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I would doubt that you'd be able to create a variable from a property name dynamically in the local scope.

Comment: I am able to succesfully do this: `var q = {[a.d]:a.d}` but I just can't destructure the whole object.

Comment: Yes, because that creates an object property, which are already able to be created dynamically. The destructuring syntax is little more than sugar over a process that can already be done. Same with the new syntax in the object literal.

Comment: `eval(\`var ${a.d} = ${a[a.d]};\`)` :P

Comment: The spec allows either `PropertyName : AssignmentElement` or `IdentifierReference` inside an object destructuring literal. `[a.d]` is not an `IdentifierReference` and you cannot have a `PropertyName` without assigning it to something.http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-destructuring-assignment

Comment: Not certain what expected result is?

Comment: Added expected result.

Comment: Lets assume this was possible, how would you access that variable (`rawr`)?

Comment: Am I missing something? Why not just `var {b, c, d, rawr} = a;`? That would get you your expected result.

Comment: Ah very good thanks @FelixKling it's not possible. So I would destructure it into `this` sow with `var {b, c, d, [d]:this} = a` then I can access it with `this[d]` correct?

Comment: You cannot assign to `this` (you could merge into it though). Why not just keep using `a[a.d]` or `a[d]`?

Comment: @timolawl I don't know that d holds string of `rawr` in it before hand.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What do you ultimately need to do?

Comment: @squint I was just exploring es6

Comment: @Noitidart Curious what the context would be at _"Expected result is that:

`var b = 1;
var c = 2;
var d = 'rawr';
var rawr = 10;`"_ Is `this` `window`?

Comment: @guest271314 `this` is a react component and its common to pass properties via `this.props` which is an array of things. I was just trying to think of ways es6 could help me just experimenting totally.

Comment: @Noitidart Note, have not tried `react`, not familiar with `this.props` pattern. Have not tried `react`.  What is purpose of creating varibles using `var` where same variables are presently accesible at `a` object? _"I was just trying to think of ways es6 could help me just experimenting totally."_ Yes, experimentation ultimately leads to progress.

Comment: Thanks @guest271314 for that support of experimentation! :) Reason I was doing it was for convience. Each element is passed an object of props. Then we can create sub elements in it, and and I have to pass just specific props to the child, so instead of doing `{blah:this.props.blah, rawr:this.props.blah}` I can do `{b, c, d, rawr}`. I was hoping to do `{b, c, d, [d]}`. I don't pass the same object as we need them immutable to a certain extent. It also makes it easier to use those props in that scope, as I don't have to go `this.props.XXX` every time.

Comment: @Noitidart Without experience with `react` not certain what exact expected result is, though `{b, c, d, rawr}` appears fairly convenient?

Comment: @guest271314 yep thats the goal I'm trying to reach. But I don't know that `rawr` key in one instance of mine. `rawr` is the value held in `d`. The most likely situation is that I should not do it like this, if I am passing in the key name I should also pass in the value of that key as well. I need the name as I do a `setState` on that key name which is basically a global update to a global store.

Comment: @Noitidart Probably not what you are trying to achieve, though tried this approach following this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040290/es6-computed-property-in-destructure-destructure-whole-object?noredirect=1#comment61632263_37040482 https://jsfiddle.net/ravkgzjb/3/

Comment: Wow that is very interesting thanks @guest271314!

Comment: Stop trying to be so clever with your code. Just because it might be possible doesn't mean you should do this. The readability is just utter trash.

Comment: @guest271314: `var [val] = this[val] = [a[val]];` is assigning an Array to each property of `this`, not just the desired value, and the `var [val] =` part is pointless since you're not using `val` anyway. The `Object.keys(a).forEach(de.bind(this));` is better written as `Object.keys(a).forEach(de, this);`. And ultimately, all this is just a long, slow way of doing this: `for (var key in a) this[key] = a[key]`, which also would have nothing to do with what is being asked.

Comment: @naomik Not sure if your comment was addressed to here? The art is in the freedom of the artists' composition, exploration; whatever form may result; without hesitancy or concern for possible criticism. "trash" [fine line] "treasure". _"mere unorganized explosions of random energy, and therefore meaningless.”[66](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_Pollock#cite_note-66) "what was to go on the canvas was not a picture but an event. The big moment came when it was decided to paint 'just to paint'. The gesture on the canvas was a gesture of liberation from value-political, aesthetic, moral."_

Comment: @squint Did not assert that had accrued a perfect interpretation of original or updated Question, or a single perfect solution deriving from the former. Note, see OP's comment at _"just experimenting totally."_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040290/es6-computed-property-in-destructure-destructure-whole-object?noredirect=1#comment61632747_37040290

Comment: @guest271314: Given that answers are expected to be on-topic and your answer contains the same info, I'd say you did implicitly make that assertion. Doesn't matter though. I'm just explaining to you some of the issues with the solution. If you use `.forEach()`, you might as well remove the `var [val]  =` part and change `this[val] = [a[val]]` to `this[val] = a[val]`, so that you'll at least have a result closer to what the OP wished to achieve. But again, a `for-in` loop will be shorter and faster, and provide the same result.

Comment: @squint Actually have no experience with `react`, still not entirely certain what expected result is, here. Though `{b, c, d, rawr}` would appear to set values from object at variables? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040290/es6-computed-property-in-destructure-destructure-whole-object?noredirect=1#comment61633069_37040290 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040290/es6-computed-property-in-destructure-destructure-whole-object?noredirect=1#comment61633086_37040290

Comment: @guest271314: The expected result is described in the question. You're absolutely right that hardcoding `rawr` would give the desired result. The OP was hoping to be able to do this dynamically though, which was the intent of the question. While this would be possible for implementers to achieve, I'm certain that if it ever were proposed for the spec, it would be quickly rejected because of the same performance and perhaps security issues inherent in similar uses of `eval`.

Comment: @squint _"You're absolutely right that hardcoding rawr would give the desired result. The OP was hoping to be able to do this dynamically though, which was the intent of the question"_ This is why tried `Object.keys()` approach, or as you pointed out, `for..in` approach would achieve the same. Where unclear, here, is where `var b = 1;
var c = 2;
var d = 'rawr';
var rawr = 10;` would be used? And why original object, or copy of original object, could not be used to reference values?

Comment: @guest271314: I'm certain that the original object could be used. ECMAScript6 added this destructuring sugar for a reason though. People sometimes want to have local variable access to certain object properties. Sometimes it's for performance since reading a value from a variable is generally faster than reading an object from a variable and then looking up one of its properties. Or maybe they want to mutate a value locally without mutating the object. Destructuring is convenient for this purpose, but not strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks for that awesome quote guest. And thanks squint for those benefits of destructuring. I am in that immutable group, where I change the var locally and passed the changed down to a child component. The original object is used by react for other things like diff checking for performance.

Comment: Thanks @guest271314 for that idea that is a totally valid method. I will for sure be thinking about my original problem a little differently. I actually already changed it so I the value `rawr` is now held in `dval`. As I know for sure now that the object will have keys `b, c, d, and dval`

Answer (score 15):

You can destructure it like this:

```
var {b, c, d, [d]: q} = a;
```

So then whatever was in a property with a name `d` is assigned to `q`.

**UPD**:

What you asked in the update is not possible.*

Comment: The value of `a.rawr` will be in the local variable `q`

Comment: In both attempts shown, he's using variable declaration syntax, while trying to use the value of `a.d`. So seems pretty obvious that he's trying to create the variable `rawr`.

Comment: Thanks very much, I added expected result to question. I'm trying to get `var rawr = 10` into the local scope. This way is awesome in that it gets `q.rawr = 10`, maybe replacd `q` with `this` huh?

Comment: @Noitidart: The only way to create a dynamic variable in local scope is via `eval`. But that won't work in strict mode...

Answer (score 7):

You need to give it a variable to assign to. You cannot use "computed" variable names<sup>1</sup>, as that would go against the rules of static scope resolution for identifiers. So you should do

```
var {b, c, d, [a.d]: rawr} = a;
```

to get the value of the `a.d`-named property in the `rawr` variable.

<sub>1: Well, you can use `eval` or a `with` statement in sloppy mode to do this, but both are despised exactly because of this.</sub>

Comment: @zerkms i upvoted you there too. However its my fault its a silly question, I was just exploring es6, forgive that please. In you trying to help me you got down voted by someone :(

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for that note on `eval` and `with` on why they are not looked upon favorably. It is a very helpful note!

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that neither `eval` nor `with` will work in strict mode (`eval` "works" but doesn't let you declare variables in the same scope). I assume that if code is written in ES6, it's more likely to be in strict mode.

Comment: @FelixKling: I was just about to add that :-)

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with computed objects property destruction the value of the string literal needs to correspond with the key name you are referencing in your object: for example

```
// string literal
const getRawr = 'd'
const { [getRaw]: rawr } = {b:1, c:2, d:'rawr', rawr:10};
console.log(raw);
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use `Object.keys()`, `Function.prototype.bind()` though caveat is that value of variable is within an array; have not yet determined how to return only variable.

```js
var a = {
  b: 1,
  c: 2,
  d: 'rawr',
  rawr: 10
};

function de(val, key) {
  var [val] = window[val] = [a[val]];
}

Object.keys(a).forEach(de.bind(this));

console.log(b, c, d, rawr);
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ravkgzjb/2/

Comment: `var [val] = [a[val]]` is identical to `var val = a[val]`

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, objects can be destructured using `[]` notation if enclosed in iterable at other side of `=`. `b`, `c`, `d` are defined outside of `.forEach()`

Comment: Array destructuring... yes. I got confused with dynamic properties, and it seems you too ;) Because `var [val]` will create a variable with *name* `val`... is that what you intended?

Comment: @FelixKling Curious why `rawr` is `undefined` though `b`, `c` and `d` are?

Comment: @FelixKling Attempting to meet requirement _"Expected result is that:

var b = 1;
var c = 2;
var d = 'rawr';
var rawr = 10;"_ _"var [val] will create a variable with name val..."_ No, try `console.log(b, c, d)` outside of `.forEach()` .  Should i include a stacksnippets?

Comment: But as @zerkms said, `var [val] = [a[val]]` is identical to `var val = a[val]`. I.e. you are simply creating a variable `val`, not variables `b`, `c`, etc.

Comment: *"No, try `console.log(b, c, d)` outside of `.forEach()`"* Why would the variables be accessible *outside* the `forEach`? You are making them *local* to `forEach` (because `var`). The variables must be coming from one of your previous experiments.

Comment: @FelixKling You are correct. Tried `console.log(val)` after destructuring within `.forEach()` and logged `1
 2
rawr
10`, now only need to port those variables outside of `.forEach()`. Will leave post undeleted; have to depart for now, but will try to get those variables outside of `.forEach()` to verify if approach will return expected results

Comment: Thanks very much @guest271314 this was an insightful discussion with you and Felix.

Comment: @zerkms _"`var [val] = [a[val]]` is identical to `var val = a[val]`"_ No, they are not identical. First version at your example assigns variable name; e.g., `b` to `[a[val]]` iterable; second version at your example creates an array having string value `a[val]`

Comment: @guest271314 "First version at your example assigns variable name" --- no it does not. `var [val] = [a[val]]` assigns the first element of the array from the RHS to the `val` variable. Your example above just demonstrated that. https://jsfiddle.net/ravkgzjb/1/ --- see that there is no difference in output with your code.

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/ravkgzjb/1/ and the output. Then compare with output of your code. "What is `[val]`" --- it is a destructuring of a first array element into the variable with the name `val`.

Comment: @zerkms Ah, you appear to be correct. Was able to achieve using `.bind()`, though return value as property of an array. See updated post

Comment: @FelixKling Found a way to define `b`, `c`, `d` , `rawr` outside of `.forEach()`, though not necessarily pleased with using `window` or result variable, for example, `b` being within and array `[1]`; see updated post

Comment: @guest271314 now try to do the same without polluting a global object (within a function)

Comment: @zerkms Yes, still trying to achieve this; actually tried first within an IIFE where could define `this` as an object other than `window`. Not certain what context is for `var b = 1;
var c = 2;
var d = 'rawr';
var rawr = 10;` at OP?

Comment: @zerkms _"now try to do the same without polluting a global object (within a function)"_ What would or should `this` be?

Comment: @zerkms _"now try to do the same without polluting a global object"_ Is not `var b = 1` equivalent to `window["b"] = 1` ? _" (within a function)"_ There does not appear to be a function at original Question?