# ES6 destructuring with dynamic key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

In case, we need to use dynamic key to parse data out of some nested object and destructure it as below, is it required to be assigned to some alias as below. I am getting compilation error otherwise.

```
const { [dynamicKey] : isAliasVarReqd } = data.something[dynamicKey]
```

Comment: If you don't assign it to an alias, what will the variable name be?

Comment: Please edit thq question and show the problem code, not the working code.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have dynamic local variables, so how would you use the value after you destructure it?

Comment: "*You need to give it a variable to assign to. You cannot use "computed" variable names, as that would go against the rules of static scope resolution for identifiers*." https://stackoverflow.com/a/37040523/3082296

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we have 'x' as a value that has to be destructured, we can pass this dynamically into our destructuring syntax using square brackets syntax [removeProp], just like an object lookup (instead this will create a new variable based off the dynamically passed value).

```
const someData = { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 };
const removeProp = 'x';

const { [removeProp]: remove } = someData;

console.log(remove); // 1
```

Because we’re dynamically constructing a new variable, we need to use : remove to reassign it to a new name.

Comment: That is what OP currently does. The question is, can it be avoided.